Change the Background of Pickers/Toggle in SwiftUI
I'm creating a basic app for meditation to continue learning SwiftUI. I am unsure how to get the Picker and Toggle views to have the same background as is being used within the Form, that is, not the .splashBackground but this line below:
.background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.opacityDark : Color.white.opacity(0.7))


    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.splashBackground
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                
                Text("Meditation Settings")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.ultraLight)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.2))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                
                Form {
                    Section {
                        Picker(selection: $meditationTime, label: Text("Meditation Time").font(.footnote)) {
                            ForEach(1..<181, id: \.self) { minute in
                                Text("\(minute) min").tag(minute)
                                    .background(Color.splashBackground)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    Section {
                        Toggle(isOn: $isCountdownEnabled) {
                            Text("Enable Countdown")
                                .font(.footnote)
                        }.tint(Color.themeAccent2)
                        
                        if isCountdownEnabled {
                            Picker(selection: $countdownTime, label: Text("Countdown Time").font(.footnote)) {
                                ForEach(Array(stride(from: 5, through: 60, by: 5)), id: \.self) { second in
                                    Text("\(second) sec").tag(second)
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Section {
                        Toggle(isOn: $isBackgroundSoundEnabled) {
                            Text("Enable Background Sound")
                                .font(.footnote)
                        }.tint(Color.themeAccent2)
                        
                        if isBackgroundSoundEnabled {
                            Picker("Background Sound", selection: $backgroundSound) {
                                ForEach(backgroundSounds, id: \.self) { sound in
                                    Text(sound).tag(sound)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Section {
                        Toggle(isOn: $isBellIntervalEnabled) {
                            Text("Enable Bell Interval")
                                .font(.footnote)
                        }.tint(Color.themeAccent2)
                        
                        if isBellIntervalEnabled {
                            Picker(selection: $bellInterval, label: Text("Bell Interval").font(.footnote)) {
                                ForEach(bellIntervals, id: \.self) { interval in
                                    Text(interval).tag(interval)
                                        .font(.footnote)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Section {
                        Toggle(isOn: $endingBell) {
                            Text("Enable Ending Bell")
                                .font(.footnote)
                        }.tint(Color.themeAccent2)
                    }
                    
                    Section {
                        Button(action: startMeditation) {
                            Text("Start Meditation")
                                .foregroundStyle(Color.themeText)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .italic()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        }
                        
                    
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.opacityDark : Color.white.opacity(0.7))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .padding()
                
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    

I've tried tint, accent, background and so on but there doesnt appear to be a built in way to change the color of the picker/toggle view itself, which remains white.

Some UI still cannot be customised in SwiftUI. You need to use UIKit tricks to do this. Look at this

This question is similar to: How to change selected segment color in SwiftUI Segmented Picker. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You should add some screenshots to better illustrate the issue, especially since you have not provided a more generic code that we can use to reproduce it. You should also add comments within the code to indicate the location of the line you're referring to.

Note: Please see my comment above about making it easier to get answers to your questions.
The problem you're having is not actually with pickers or toggles, as you're already affecting the color of the toggle using .tint().
The actual problem is with the backgrounds of each Form row. A Form acts much like a List, in that it provides its own default styling. This means you can actually use List modifiers to change the appearance, in most cases.
So to remove the default background of every row (Section in your case), add the .listRowBackground modifier with a clear color for every section:
Section {
       Toggle(isOn: $endingBell) {
       Text("Enable Ending Bell")
           .font(.footnote)
       }
       .tint(Color.themeAccent2)
}
.listRowBackground(Color.clear) // <-- This removes the background of a row/section, allowing for the background colour to be shown

